# Odoo 12 python write xls File fails (PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:)

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I generate xls file from odoo, the code works in my laptop but in server machine it doesn't
i tried the both commands:

1- sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/

2-sudo chown -R 777 /odoo/

but nothing has changed

Thanks for help

File code  of module dangerous.product.wizard

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
# here is the file of generation xls file 
from datetime import timedelta
import xlwt
from odoo import models, fields, api, _


class LiberationPfWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'dangerous.product.wizard'

    date_from = fields.Date(string='From', required=True, default=fields.Date.today().replace(month=1, day=1))
    date_to = fields.Date(string='To', required=True, default=fields.Date.today().replace(month=12, day=31))
    product_ids = fields.Many2many('product.product',
                                   string="Products list",
                                   default=lambda self: self.env['product.product'].search([('is_dangerous', '=', True)]))

    @api.multi
    def print_report_xls(self):
        workbook = self.sudo().create_workbook()
        return self.env['report.xls'].report_action(workbook, _('Dangerous product Excel'))

    def get_report_lines(self):
        lines = []
        product_ids = self.env['product.product'].with_context(dict(self.env.context, to_date=self.date_from)).search([
            ('id', 'in', self.product_ids.ids)
        ])
        for product_id in product_ids:
            data = {
                'product_name': product_id.name,
                'product_technical_description': product_id.technical_description,
                'onu_number': product_id.onu_number,
            }
            moves = self.env['stock.move'].search([
                ('state', '=', 'done'),
                ('product_id', '=', product_id.id),
                ('date', '>=', self.date_from),
                ('date', '<', self.date_to + timedelta(days=1)),
            ])
            in_qty = sum(moves.filtered(
                lambda move: move.location_id.usage in ['customer', 'supplier', 'inventory'] and move.location_dest_id.usage == 'internal'
            ).mapped('quantity_done'))
            out_qty = sum(moves.filtered(
                lambda move: move.location_id.usage == 'internal' and move.location_dest_id.usage in ['production', 'customer', 'supplier', 'inventory']
            ).mapped('quantity_done'))
            data['initial_stock'] = product_id.qty_available
            data['in_qty'] = in_qty
            data['out_qty'] = out_qty
            lines.append(data)
        return lines

    def create_workbook(self):
        lines = self.get_report_lines()

        date_from = self.date_from
        date_to = self.date_to
        workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
        xlwt.add_palette_colour("teal", 0x21)
        workbook.set_colour_RGB(0x21, 0, 128, 128)
        xlwt.add_palette_colour("magenta", 0x22)
        workbook.set_colour_RGB(0x22, 224, 17, 95)
        xlwt.add_palette_colour("light_grey", 0x23)
        workbook.set_colour_RGB(0x23, 222, 222, 222)

        colorized = xlwt.easyxf(
            'font:height 220,bold True;pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour light_grey;align: horiz center, vert center; '
            'border: left thin,right thin,top thin,bottom thin')
        value = xlwt.easyxf(
            'font:height 220;align: horiz center, vert center;border: left thin,right thin,top thin,bottom thin')
        teal = xlwt.easyxf(
            'font:height 220,colour white,bold True;pattern: pattern solid, '
            'fore_colour teal;align: horiz center, vert center; '
            'border: left thin,right thin,top thin,bottom thin')
        magenta = xlwt.easyxf(
            'font:height 220,colour white,bold True;pattern: pattern solid, '
            'fore_colour magenta;align: horiz center, vert center; '
            'border: left thin,right thin,top thin,bottom thin')
        sheet = workbook.add_sheet(_('Liberation PF'))

        sheet.write_merge(1, 1, 0, 6, _('Monthly Declaration of Dangerous Raw Materials'), magenta)
        sheet.write_merge(2, 2, 0, 6, _('FROM %s TO %s') % (str(date_from), str(date_to)), teal)
        sheet.write(3, 0, _('NAME'), colorized)
        sheet.write(3, 1, _('TECHNICAL DESCRIPTION'), colorized)
        sheet.write(3, 2, _('N° ONU-CAS-CEE-EINCS'), colorized)
        sheet.write(3, 3, _('STOCK AT %s') % str(self.date_from - timedelta(days=1)), colorized)
        sheet.write(3, 4, _('ENTERED'), colorized)
        sheet.write(3, 5, _('QUANTITY USED'), colorized)
        sheet.write(3, 6, _('BALANCE AT %s') % str(self.date_to), colorized)
        l = 4
        for line in lines:
            sheet.write(l, 0, line.get('product_name'), value)
            sheet.write(l, 1, line.get('product_technical_description') or '/', value)
            sheet.write(l, 2, line.get('onu_number') or '/', value)
            sheet.write(l, 3, line.get('initial_stock'), value)
            sheet.write(l, 4, line.get('in_qty'), value)
            sheet.write(l, 5, line.get('out_qty'), value)
            sheet.write(l, 6, abs(line.get('initial_stock') + line.get('in_qty') - line.get('out_qty')), value)
            l += 1

        sheet.col(0).width = 256 * 48
        sheet.col(1).width = 256 * 72
        sheet.col(2).width = 256 * 48
        for i in range(3, 7):
            sheet.col(i).width = 256 * 28
        return workbook
```

File code  of module report.xls  Error  in server machine only in line  line 21, in report_action **workbook.save(filename)**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import base64

from odoo import models, fields, api, _
from odoo.exceptions import UserError


class ReportXLS(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "report.xls"
    _description = "Report xls"

    file_name = fields.Binary('Excel Report', readonly=True, attachment=True)
    data = fields.Binary('File', readonly=True)
    name = fields.Char('Filename', readonly=True)

    @api.model
    def report_action(self, workbook, filename=_("XLS REPORT")):
        if workbook:
            filename = '%s.%s' % (filename, 'xls')
            workbook.save(filename)
            file = open(filename, "rb")
            file_data = file.read()
            out = base64.encodebytes(file_data)
            record = self.env['report.xls'].create({
                'file_name': out,
                'data': out,
                'name': filename
            })
            return {
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'res_model': 'report.xls',
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'view_type': 'form',
                'res_id': record.id,
                'target': 'new',
            }
        raise UserError(
            _('There is no XLS File to print !')
        )
```

Here the full error's message

> Erreur: Odoo Server Error
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
>       return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
>       raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py",
>   line 87, in reraise
>       raise value   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
>       result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
>       return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
>       return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
>       result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 941, in **call**
>       return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
>       response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 966, in
>   call_button
>       action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})   File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in
>   _call_kw
>       return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 749, in call_kw
>       return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)   File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 736, in _call_kw_multi
>       result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)   File "/odoo/custom/lsee/quality_pharm_report/wizard/dangerous_product_balance_wizard.py",
>   line 20, in print_report_xls
>       return self.env['report.xls'].report_action(workbook, _('Dangerous product Excel'))   File
>   "/odoo/custom/lsee/report_xls/wizard/report_xls.py", line 21, in
>   report_action
>       workbook.save(filename)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 710,
>   in save
>       doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xlwt/CompoundDoc.py", line
>   262, in save
>       f = open(file_name_or_filelike_obj, 'w+b') PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Produits dangereux Excel.xls'

Comment: It's the location of the file you're trying to write to which is throwing the error, not the executable.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion
Thanks

Comment: You have provided no code, so all we can do is guess where the problem lies.

Comment: Also the error points out exactly what file it cannot access: `Produits dangereux Excel.xls`

Comment: i added the code thanks for help

Comment: Sometimes this error is shown if the file is open in another program.

Comment: i added full code ( two files ) thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to the solution Odoo itself is using for its reports or export files: use `/tmp` as temporarily (pun intended) file directory. On "normal" or "usual" server configurations, this directory can be used by nearly all applications without thinking about file access.

So you have to change the path your custom module is using for creating the Excel file. (Can't help further, because you didn't share your code)

Comment: The `filename` is just a relative path in context of execution. Just add the tmp directory and make it a absolute filepath -> `'/tmp/' + filename`.